# Google Chrome speed problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I've stubmled upon a strange Google Chrome problem. 
I'm making a simple script for gallery that is using jQuery slideToggle to show and hide list of thumbnails. In the latest versions of IE and Firefox it works just fine, but in Google Chrome the sliding animation is working with really noticeable lags. Can anybody tell me please, is this a common Chrome problem? Is there any workaround for it?

The div I'm using slideToggle on is:

```
<div class="ivg_items_wrap">
<div class="ivg_items">
    <div><img src="/ivg_images/001_ivg.jpg" alt="" title=""></div>
    .....
    <div><img src="/ivg_images/nnn_ivg.jpg" alt="" title=""></div>
</div>
</div>
```

There are 32 images in div total. Every image is something like 7kb big and has size of 100x100 pixels.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a link, or show us a demo?

Comment: Also, 32 images seems a bit excessive! Do you really need that many?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I can't, I thought maybe this was a common issue.

Comment: Even if i set the number of images to ten or less, the lags still remain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out a Chrome DevTools profiler: Ctrl-Shift-I, select the Profiles panel at the top, hit the Record button in the status bar, and run your lagging animation. Then stop the profiler (hit the glowing Record button again) and examine the profile. If the most time-consuming line is "(program)", then your issue is related to the Chrome internals. Otherwise, it's the slow JavaScript code (is your hardware powerful enough?)

Comment: The program is taking 99,6% of time. This isn't about hardware - as I said, everything is running smoothly on IE and Firefox.

Comment: You are correct, given the profile, this is the browser code being slow. Feel free to file a bug using http://new.crbug.com (but search for a similar bug before filing.)

Comment: Finally found cause of the lag, apparently it was setting the box-shadow style of the container.